# How do I read an environment variable in Verilog/System Verilog?

Tags: environment-variables, verilog, system-verilog

How do I read an environment variable in Verilog ? (Running on a VCS simulator)

I am trying to accomplish

```
File=$fopen("$PATH/FileName","r");
```

$PATH is an environment variable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply use SystemVerilog DPI for getting environment.
And because `getenv` is a standard C library for every POSIX platform, so you do not need to implement your own `getenv()` equivalent function for the function definition again.

Example code in SV.

```
import "DPI-C" function string getenv(input string env_name);

module top;

  initial begin
    $write("env = %s\n", {getenv("HOME"), "/FileName"});
  end
endmodule
```

Running

```
ncverilog -sv dpi.v
```

or

```
vcs -sverilog dpi.v
```

It will show

```
env = /home/user/FileName
```

And one more issue in your original question, PATH is a environment for executable search path and concatenate with ":" character. I think it should be an example here, not really "PATH" environment. Otherwise, your fopen file name could be `"/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/FileName"`, which is wrong.

Comment: This is not a solution for `include path. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple PLI application to read an environment variable. Here's a sample, without any error checks:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "vpi_user.h"

PLI_INT32 pli_getenv (PLI_BYTE8 * arg) {

    vpiHandle tf_obj = vpi_handle (vpiSysTfCall, NULL);
    vpiHandle arg_iter = vpi_iterate (vpiArgument, tf_obj);

    vpiHandle arg1, arg2;
    arg1 = vpi_scan (arg_iter);
    arg2 = vpi_scan (arg_iter);

    s_vpi_value vi, vo;
    vi.format = vpiStringVal;
    vpi_get_value (arg2, &vi);

    vo.format = vpiStringVal;
    vo.value.str = strdup (getenv (vi.value.str));
    vpi_put_value (arg1, &vo, NULL, vpiNoDelay);

    return 0;
}
```

The VCS documentation should explain how to link this into the simulator.

Comment: This is so much simpler using DPI. See the other answer.

Comment: good point - why is a PLI function useful here ?

Answer (score 1):

It is often simpler to use the Verilog preprocessor

```
File = $fopen(`PATH_FILENAME, "r");
```

Then invoke the simulator from your Makefile/shell script the specifying value to be substituted

`$(SIM) -DPATH_FILENAME=\"$PATH/FileName\" blah.v ...`

I use this with Icarus' `iverilog` often, `vsim` and friends probably support similar.

Quotes are escaped so that they are included in the substituted value, since the preprocessor will not substitute inside a literal value. For instance this combination does *not work*:

```
File = $fopen("`PATH_FILENAME", "r");
```

...

```
`$(SIM) -DPATH_FILENAME=$PATH/FileName blah.v ...`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I can see all answers, either they are using some DPI Or need some command line arguments. So I am sharing my answer with *only SystemVerilog* syntax.  Answer is **not specific to any simulator**. But surely it is for Linux environment; for other OS we need to change *$system* commands.

> We need to set this "logPath" system variable using some pre
> processing script or by simulation script before we start our
> simulation.

```
 string myPath;

 initial begin
     //Writing System Variable To A File
     $system("echo ${logPath} > logPath.txt");

     //Opening that file and reading to a string variable
     fh = $fopen ("./logPath.txt", "r");
     void'($fscanf(fh,"%s",myPath));

     //Appending File Name To That Path
     myPath = {myPath,"/note.txt"};

     //Closed and remove this temporary file
     $fclose(fh);
     $system("rm -rf logPath.txt");
      
     //Open a file at the path that you have extracted from System Variable
     //Do whatever you want now 
     fh = $fopen (myPath, "w");
     
     repeat(10) begin
         $fdisplay (fh, "%t %M: Write Line Number =|%0d| ", $time, i);
         i++;
     end

     $fclose(fh);
  end
```